# fixed position and fixed background attachment "ignores" the background image in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Here is the CSS:

```
body > .section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    min-height: 1080px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

body > .section.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
}

body > .section.fixed-next {
    margin-top: 1080px;   
}

#city {
    background-image: url('../img/bg_baku1.jpg');
    background-position: 50% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: white;
}
```

the html,

```
<div class="section fixed" id="city">
    <!-- Content here -->
</div>

<div class="section fixed-next" id="contact">
    <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

The result in chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzdr9.jpg

In every other browser it shows the background image. If i turn off `position:fixed` or the `background-attachment: fixed`, Chrome shows it normally. I am guessing thats a Chrome bug. So my question is... Is there a way I can at least turn the `background-attachment: fixed` attribute only for chrome?

Comment: I have created the jsfiddle with your code and it is working fine. Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MFWj8/

Comment: i didnt really know what the problem was as it was appearing problematic on my iphone also. So i just removed the fixed position attribute and everything is fine now.